# an introduction to axiomatic set theory that is not enderton

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I've been reading Endertons Elements of set theory which is easy to understand when it comes to the essential axioms, but there are a number of topics which seem to gloss over important information, as if the it were self explanatory. An example of one the confusing parts of the book which I am currently reading is the definition of the domain and range of a function; initially this makes sense, but then there is the use of a set with two consecutive arbitrary unions thrown in without any explanation. I don't know what this is, why its being used, or if this is some kind of error. Please correct me if I've made a mistake here but are there any more suitable books for introductory axiomatic set theory or is this the way I'm supposed to learn, by being exposed to ideas that are explained later on.

Comment: Are you talking about Lemma 3D?

Comment: Give us the exactly information about where in the book is your doubt.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time, I've found out what my problem was. Just for future reference can you delete your own questions?